# Wiki rendering engine for C#? like redcloth, bluecloth, or something decent

Tags: c#, wiki

We have used the redcloth and bluecloth wiki renderer's with Ruby, basically you can do something like this...

html = RedCloth.to_html(wiki_content)

and poof, you get back HTML.

Is there something out there for C#/.NET ?

Answer (score 2):

try http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/

Comment: That will result in incompatible wiki syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are some wiki rendering engines but the names escape me right now. Perhaps check out some of these [open-source options](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/wiki-engines)? I've previously reviewed [MindTouch](http://wiki.developer.mindtouch.com/Deki_Wiki) from that list for an application and it was quite rich, but it did much more than I needed to do.

If you just need something to turn text into HTMLcontent, I use [Halide](http://www.codeplex.com/halide) which lets people type in a textarea then it'll HTML-ify links, remove dangerous content, add `<p></p>` and `<br />`, etc. Very simple but no built-in formatting options.

SO uses a custom version of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for their text editor and HTML content rendering. [Search google for Markdown.NET](http://www.google.com/search?q=markdown.net) for a number of ports.