# Replace with .Replace/.Regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `Html.Raw(Html.Encode())` to allow some of html to be allowed. For example I want bold, italic, code etc... I am not sure it's the right method, code seems pretty ugly.

### Input

> Hello, this text will be [b]bold[/b]. [code]alert("Test...")[/code]

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
    @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Body)
    .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
    .Replace("[b]", "<b>")
    .Replace("[/b]", "</b>")
    .Replace("[code]", "<div class='codeContainer'><pre name='code' class='javascript'>")
    .Replace("[/code]", "</pre></div>"))
```

### My Solution

I want to make it all a bit different. Instead of using BB-Tags I want to use simpler tags.
For example `*` will stand for bold. That means if I input `This text is *bold*.` it will replace text to `This text is <b>bold</b>.`. Kinda like this website is using BTW.

### Problem

To implement this I need some Regex and I have little to no experience with it. I've searched many sites, but no luck.

My implementation of it looks something like this, but it fails since I can't really replace a `char` with `string`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myString = "Hello, this text is *bold*, this text is also *bold*. And this is code: ~MYCODE~";
    string findString = "\\*";
    int firstMatch, nextMatch;

    Match match = Regex.Match(myString, findString);

    while (match.Success == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
        firstMatch = match.Index;
        match = match.NextMatch();
        if (match.Success == true)
        {
            nextMatch = match.Index;

            myString = myString[firstMatch] = "<b>"; // Ouch!
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450937/wiki-rendering-engine-for-c-like-redcloth-bluecloth-or-something-decent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To implement this I need some Regex

Ah no, you don't need Regex. Manipulating HTML with Regex could lead to some [undesired effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). So you could simply use [MarkDownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) which by the way is what this site uses to safely render [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) markup into HTML.

Like this:

```
var markdown = new Markdown();
string html = markdown.Transform(SomeTextContainingMarkDown);
```

Of course to polish this you would write an HTML helper so that in your view:

```
@Html.Markdown(Model.Body)
```

Comment: And all it does basically is same as Html.Encode()? I searched and all I could find about it is that it will encode HTML.

Comment: @Qmal, oh no, it does much more than this. It converts the Markdown string into HTML. It does what you see on this site: a user types Markdown in the Question/Answer textarea and when he submits it you can see the final resulting HTML.

Comment: Can you give me a short example please, I mean with the markup itself. I can't seem to find this option in google on this library.

Comment: @Qmal, here are some examples of Markdown strings: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Now simply apply the code I have shown in my answer to such a string.

Comment: Ahhh, so I just need to add it like you showed above and don't need to hardcode searching for "*" and it will work?

Comment: @Qmal, here's an example: `var markdown = new Markdown(); var text = "**Hello** *World*"; Console.WriteLine(markdown.Transform(text));`. It will generate `<p><strong>Hello</strong> <em>World</em></p>`.

Comment: Okey thanks a lot. Just one more question - can I disable certain feautures? All I need is bold. Thanks again.